# Libero, smartdesign, CoreEDAC

Tags: fpga

I have got Libero SoC 11.5 and when I click on SmartDesign Tab its open only one string, - "Refresh F5" in drop-down list.
I need SmartDesign to  instantiate CoreEDAC, but without it I can't do that.
Can anybody know in what problem and how to solve this?
And also maybe somebody know where is now ACTEL's IP Catalog Web Repository?

Thanks!